# Single Sentence definition of Lorentz Transform

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, definition

Dear fellow physics lovers,

After having spent some significant time to understand the Lorentz Transformations the following is the most simple and complete single sentence definition of it that I have been able to think of.

A ***Lorentz Transform*** (also known as a ***Lorentz Boost***) are a **Set of Linear Equations** that Transform the ***Percieved Position $\vec{r}$ of an Object O*** and ***Percieved Ellapsed Time***
from the Point of View of a ***Static Observer A*** to the Point of View of a ***Non-Static Observer B*** which is moving at a relative ***Constant Velocity*** $\vec{v}$ with respect to ***Observer A*** after a certain ***Ellapsed Time*** *t*.

Please let me know whether the above qualifies as a correct single sentence definition of Lorentz Transform.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I will appreciate if someone can provide a simpler / more appropriate single sentence definition that does not involve usage of primed and unprimed coordinates
and/or variables and also does not use the words spacetime and frame

The goal is to update the definition Lorentz Transformation in Wikipedia with this single sentence. I think it will be useful to many people who have just begun to learn about
Special Relativity/Lorentz Transform from the Internet.

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but if you don't know already very well relativity, may I suggest that you _don't_ update any related Wikipedia definition? Note also that whatever definition you come up, it'd be probably removed or heavily edited by more senior curators of the definition. Finally, I wouldn't suggest to anyone who has just begun to learn about special relativity and Lorentz transformations from the Internet to use Wikipedia as reference.

Comment: Ok. I have understood that the definition that I have provided is correct for a single Lorentz Boost (at least in the context of the 2 equations, one for time and one for position) that are generally used to explain Special Relativity. It is not correct for all Lorentz Transformation.  Thanks to all of you who took the time out to answer this question and enhance my knowledge.

Comment: "A Lorentz Transform (also known as a Lorentz Boost)..." - The first part of this sentence is already incorrect. Everything else after that is completely misleading, if not incorrect (for instance - a Lorentz transform is NOT an equation or equations). I would ask you to not update a Wikipedia entry on any topic on which you are not yourself an expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost correct. But

> A Lorentz Transform (also known as a Lorentz Boost) ...

this statement of yours is not correct. A Lorentz transformation is not exactly the same as the Lorentz boost. Even if two different coordinates systems are such that one is just a rotation of the other and each is at rest with respect to the other, their transformation is still considered as a Lorentz transformation. A Lorentz boost is a rotation-free Lorentz transformation.

> ... View of a Static Observer A to the Point of View of a Non-Static Observer B which is moving at a relative Constant Velocity $\bar{v}$ with respect to Observer A after a certain Elapsed Time t.

Even this statement is not completely correct. You have to replace `observer` with the `coordinate system`. A coordinate system is a group of imaginary clocks that are synchronized. If you consider a point observer then the observer is a single clock. The observer does not measure the time we get from the transformations, he actually measures the time after considering the time taken for light to reach him from the position where the event happened. Also, you are specifying static observer and nonstatic observer, if you are saying this with respect to one of the observers it is correct, but if you are assuming one of them is at absolute rest then that is wrong as it violates the first postulate of Special Relativity.

Also, don't update the definitions on Wikipedia, they are technically more correct.

**Edit**: (Some points from Comments)

Every 3d rotation can be expressed as a Lorentz transformation. Also, center inversion and mirror inversions are also Lorentz transformations.
If the velocity of A with respect to B is v then the difference in velocities of A and B with respect to C won't have a magnitude v in general. This is only possible in some cases like where A and B are moving in the same direction with respect to C. In general, it is not true. The reason is a consequence of the fact that consecutive nonparallel Loretz boosts are not Lorentz boosts. It actually is a product of a pure rotation and a pure Lorentz boost.
A good reference where these are properly discussed is https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Special_Relativity/U3fADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: If you think a single Lorentz Transformation is not the same as a single Lorentz Boost how come they are represented by the same set of linear equations and same matrix?  Please refer to "Vector transformations" and "Proper transformations" section of Lorentz Transformation in Wikipedia. Also every observer and object is a coordinate system in itself. Also when 2 observers are at a constant relative velocity wrt each other, one can be assumed to be static while the other moving.

Comment: @ArupHore A pure rotation is not a Lorentz boost but it is a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: @ArupHore You haven't mentioned properly from which frame you are saying Observer A is static.

Comment: You might be right on this. Can you give me an example of a single Lorentz transformation that represents pure rotation in form of equations

Comment: Since Observer A and B are in constant relative velocity V wrt each other every observer (whether it is a third Observer C or the Observer A or B) can consider one to be static and one to be in motion based on their choice. This especially is right for observers A and B

Comment: See II.1. in this pdf. [http://home.ku.edu.tr/~amostafazadeh/phys517_518/phys517_2016f/Handouts/A_Jaffi_Lorentz_Group.pdf](http://home.ku.edu.tr/~amostafazadeh/phys517_518/phys517_2016f/Handouts/A_Jaffi_Lorentz_Group.pdf)

Comment: I am not familiar with how and when the metric signatures are used. Can you convert the metric signature you have provided into corresponding Lorentz transformation equation?

Comment: @ArupHore Also, it seems you are assuming that if the velocity of A with respect to B is v then the difference in velocities of A and B with respect to C will also have a magnitude v. This is only possible in some case like where A and B are moving in the same direction with respect C. In general, it is not true. The reason is a consequence of the fact that consecutive nonparallel Loretz boosts are not Lorentz boosts. It actually is a product of a pure rotation and a pure lorentz boost.

Comment: @ArupHore I cant use LaTeX in comments so it is tough to write a matrix.

Comment: Based on the cursory glance of the document link that you provided I have understood that Lorentz Boost is just one of the many possible kinds of Lorentz transformation. Am I correct in this observation?

Comment: @ArupHore Yes, you are correct. If you want a reference check this book. [https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Special_Relativity/U3fADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Special_Relativity/U3fADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Also I think the part where I say relative motion of 2 observers A and B wrt the third observer C is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the book reference. Will it be correct to say that the definition that I have provided is correct for a single Lorentz Boost?

Comment: @ArupHore Yes, for a single Lorentz boost it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the information.

Answer (score 2):

'Elapsed' time is unhelpful. It implies two times, a start and a finish.

It is wrong to talk about 'static' and 'non-static' observers. Both observers have to be on an equal footing.

Any $x,y,z,t$ refers to an *event*. Not an object (except by coincidence). This area of SR is all about events and their co-ordinates, and any definition of the Lorentz Transformtion should be framed in this language.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a correct definition of the Lorentz Transformation (LT):

It is a **linear** transformation between the spacetime coordinates of two inertial reference frames in relative motion that satisfy 1) **[the principle of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity#:%7E:text=The%20special%20principle%20of%20relativity,vary%20across%20non%2Dinertial%20ones.&text=The%20principle%20requires%20physical%20laws,for%20a%20body%20at%20rest.)** and 2) **The constancy of the speed of light** in all inertial reference frames.

Your definition fails for the following:

1. It is generic/ not unique to the LT. Your definition could as well apply to the Galilean transformation. This is because your definition does not specify the two above conditions that must be satisfied by the LT (especially condition 2).
2. Your definition refers to the transformation of single points in space (i.e., positions) and **elapsed** times (i.e., time intervals). Actually, LT (and even Galilean transformation) transforms spacetime **events** between two inertial coordinates. A spacetime event is something that happens at **single point** in space and time (i.e., instant). Meanwhile, elapsed time refers to an interval which is the difference between two instants*.
3. Your definition fails to specify that the transformation must be **linear**.
4. In the last sentence you say

> with respect to Observer A after a certain Elapsed Time t.

Even if we were to disregard the previous point about elapsed times, this fails to specify elapsed time with respect to which observer (A? B? other?). Elapsed times are in fact relative in LT.

*Of course, LT allows you to transform time and space intervals (i.e., the difference between two positions and the difference between their corresponding instants) between two inertial frames. But in your definition, you say it transforms position (i.e., point in space, an event) after elapsed time t (the difference between two points in time, a time interval). This is inconsistent. You should either stick to events or intervals.

Comment: I am in Agreement with the point no. 3. Have included the word Linear.

Comment: Regarding other points we need to have a detail discussion. Do you know how to start a chat here

Comment: @ArupHore You can write your comments briefly here and I'll try my best to answer.